# C casting from uint32_t* to void *

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers

I have a question about pointer casting for C.

if I have a function with this signature:

`uint8_t input_getc(void)`

which reads user input from STDIN.

Then I have  a pointer

`void* buffer`

that I store return values from `input_getc()` in.  What would be the proper way to cast this?

```
//read user input
for(i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
{
    uint8_t temp = input_getc();

    //copy to void* buffer
    *(uint8_t *)(buffer + i) = temp //WAY #1
    *(buffer + i) = (void *)temp;   //WAY #2
}
```

Are both of these the same?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As it is right now, neither of those methods will compile. Since `buffer` is a `void*` you can't do arithmetic on it since it has an unknown size.

It's not entirely clear exactly where you are trying to store it. If you're just trying to store the `uint8_t` into the memory location pointed by `buffer` with offset `i`, then it can be done like this:

```
((uint8_t*)buffer)[i] = temp;
```

**EDIT :**

Okay, apparently arithmetic on `void*` is allowed in C, but not in C++. However, doing so it still considered unsafe behavior.

See this question: [Pointer arithmetic for void pointer in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523145/pointer-arithmetic-for-void-pointer-in-c)

Comment: -1 you can not dereferencing void* pointer but you can do arrithmetic operation with pointer value (not its pointe value) see this link http://codepad.org/7YHCYz5Q

Comment: @Mr.32: I disagree. Just because GCC allows it doesn't mean it's what the standard says. As I have already demonstrated, VS2010 rejects arithmetic on void pointers.

Comment: @Mysticial lets find out what is truth in standard c language draft

Comment: @Mr.32: I just double-checked this. In C it's allowed, but in C++, it is forbidden. I'll update my answer to address this. So yes, you are right.

Comment: @Mysticial if you have any snipped shot from standard c language draft then also put that i will upvote ur answer..!!

Comment: @Mr.32: See this question: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523145/pointer-arithmetic-for-void-pointer-in-c) So it looks like GCC allows it, but it is still considered unsafe. But the answers are still very conflicting.

Comment: @Mysticial yea you seems right because i am also not getting something perfect/standard about that.

Comment: @Mr.32, for the standard pointer arithmetic is only allowed for "pointers to object type", which is the terminology of the standard for the opposite of "incomplete type". `void*` is explicitly defined to be a pointer to an incomplete type. And the reasoning for that is simple, what would the byte increment be? 1 (as `char`) or the most convenient word size of the platform? So no, for standard C this is undefined behavior, but gcc (and some gcc like derivatives) accept this as an  extension.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is:

```
*(((uint8_t*)buffer)+i) = temp;
```

Comment: how is this different from what I have above?

Comment: Performing arithmetic on a void pointer is not valid C. A compiler which accepts such a program is incorrect and buggy.

Comment: as R says, Performing arithmetic on a void pointer is not valid C, so, you must first cast the void pointer to uint8_t pointer.

Comment: hmm I thought that the cast happened before the addition would take place. Thanks for the information

Answer (score 2):

i am not understanding what do you mean by

```
 copying to  `void* buffer`
```

but if you are doing following thing then way1 is right

```
int main()
{
    int i;
    char a[10];
    void *buffer;
    buffer = &a;   // buffer is void* type pointer and its pointing to some buffer then
    for(i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        uint8_t temp = 65;

        //copy to void* buffer
        *(uint8_t *)(buffer + i) = temp; //WAY #1

    }
    printf("\n %s",a);
}
```

**BIG Edit :**

**IN WAY1**

you are adding +i offcet with void * buffer and  still whole result is void* then you are typecasting that whole result with uint8_t* then accesing that value so it works

**but in way2** you are adding +i offcet with void * buffer still whole result is void* and then you are accesing that value ...**which is completely wrong..** 
you will get warning/error here

```
 warning: dereferencing ‘void *’ pointer
```

**One more Edit :**

you can not dereferencing void* pointer but you can do arrithmetic operation with pointer value (not its pointe value)

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was doing. I know that this works because I took it from a piece of working code. But I was wondering if method two was better practice. + 1

Comment: Actually, no, this won't compile. You can't do `buffer + i` because you can't do arithmetic on a `void*`. On VS2010 the error is: `error C2036: 'void *' : unknown size`

Comment: @Mysticial in gcc i dont have any error...you can not dereferencing void* pointer but you can do arrithmetic operation with pointer value (not its pointe value) okey

Comment: @HunterMcMillen way1 is completely right so go ahead with that..way2 is totaly wrong okey

Comment: I'll +1 this, then since we're both right and that talk has been very constructive.