# How are pointers actually made to increment by the type their type

Tags: c++, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

How are pointers made to increment by their type. 
For example if we have

```
int *ptr;       
ptr++;   //would point to the next integer i.e. it would increment ptr by 4bytes in 32 bit system
```

I wanted to know that how is this done internally.

Comment: Google _pointer arithmetic_.

Comment: Related : [Declaring type of pointers?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20407747/1708801)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler compiling the code knows the base type of the pointer, and it puts the code to increment pointer (offset) appropriately. For example:

```
int* p = new int[10];
*(p+2) = 100;
```

The second line will be like:

```
p + sizeof(int) * 2 ... // Not C/C++
```

And, similary:

```
p++;
```

Would mean:

```
p = p + sizeof(int); // Not C/C++
```

If type of `p` is something else (like `float` or some structure), the calculations would be performed appropriately. There is no magic. Types are compile time defined - a type of variable don't change at runtime, hence the calculations.