# Issue with a generic stack library

Tags: c, pointers, stack, void

I am trying to write a generic stack library[using arrays] which could allocate a stack for any element size and number of elements. I am trying the below code. 
First of all i get a warning saying that i am dereferencing a void pointer when used in memcpy.

Second is i am having some issue in the output that i am trying to print. Please help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct _stk_
{
    int top;
    int elemsize;
    int numElem;
    void *array;
}stack;

stack *create_stack(int elemsize, int numElem)
{
    stack *stk_handle = malloc(sizeof(stack));

    if(!stk_handle)
    {
        printf("Malloc failed for stack handle\r\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    stk_handle->top = -1;
    stk_handle->elemsize = elemsize;
    stk_handle->numElem = numElem;
    stk_handle->array = calloc(elemsize, numElem);

    if(!(stk_handle->array))
    {
        printf("Malloc failed for stack\r\n");
        free(stk_handle);
        return NULL;
    }

    return stk_handle;
}

void push (stack *stk_handle, void *element)
{
    memcpy(&(stk_handle->array[++stk_handle->top]), element, stk_handle->elemsize);
    printf("Pushed element %s to stack. Top is %d\r\n", element, stk_handle->top);
}

void pop (stack *stk_handle, void *element)
{
    memcpy(element, &(stk_handle->array[stk_handle->top--]), stk_handle->elemsize);
    printf("Popped element %s from stack. Top is %d\r\n", element, stk_handle->top);
}

int main()
{
    stack *stk_handle = NULL;
    char string1[] = "close";
    char string2[] = "the";
    char string3[] = "door";
    char string4[6], string5[6],string6[6];

    stk_handle = create_stack(6, 5);
    push(stk_handle, &(string1));
    push(stk_handle, &(string2));
    push(stk_handle, &(string3));
    pop(stk_handle, string4);
    pop(stk_handle, string5);
    pop(stk_handle, string6);
    return 1;
}
```

When i compile I get below compilation warning.

```
$ gcc stack_lib.c
stack_lib.c: In function âpushâ:
stack_lib.c:39: warning: dereferencing âvoid *â pointer
stack_lib.c: In function âpopâ:
stack_lib.c:45: warning: dereferencing âvoid *â pointer
```

And when i run the program, I get below output:

```
Pushed element close to stack. Top is 0
Pushed element the to stack. Top is 1
Pushed element door to stack. Top is 2
Popped element door from stack. Top is 1
Popped element tdoor from stack. Top is 0
Popped element ctdoortdoor from stack. Top is -1
```

Please let me know where i am going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its the `stk_handle->array[...]` that's the `void pointer` dereference. Since the `array` member is a `void` pointer, you can't dereference it directly (either with the dereference operator `*` or using array-syntax like you do) without casting to a concrete type.

Remember that with array indexing the compiler uses the index multiplied with the base type to get the offset to the correct entry. When you have a `void*` what is the base type? `void` is not a valid base type by itself, so what should the compiler multiply the index with? It simply will not work.

My suggestion is to have a `int8_t` pointer instead, and then multiply the `top` with the element size:

```
typedef struct _stk_
{
    int top;
    int elemsize;
    int numElem;
    int8_t *array;
}stack;

...

memcpy(stk_handle->array + (++stk_handle->top * stk_handle->elmsize), ...);
```

Comment: Awesome ! How stupid for me not to notice that i have to multiply top * elemsize to index the array. Thanks ! And great explanation on the void pointer dereferencing as well ! Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

1. Those `dereferencing void * pointer` warnings could be fixed by using proper pointer arithmetic:

   ```
   void push (stack *stk_handle, void *element)
   {
           memcpy((char *)stk_handle->array + ++stk_handle->top * stk_handle->elemsize, element, stk_handle->elemsize);
           printf("Pushed element %s to stack. Top is %d\r\n", (char *)element, stk_handle->top);
   }

   void pop (stack *stk_handle, void *element)
   {
           memcpy(element, (char *)stk_handle->array + stk_handle->top-- * stk_handle->elemsize, stk_handle->elemsize);
           printf("Popped element %s from stack. Top is %d\r\n", (char *)element, stk_handle->top);
   }
   ```

   If you are using `gcc`, then the type-casting before stk_handle is unnecessary, see [Pointer arithmetic for void pointer in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523145/pointer-arithmetic-for-void-pointer-in-c).
2. The `&` operation in `push(stk_handle, &(string1));` is unnecessary, you could just write

   ```
   push(stk_handle, string1);
   push(stk_handle, string2);
   push(stk_handle, string3);
   ```

Comment: Thanks ! Yes noted that & was not required.

Comment: @ShankarNarayanan In SO, upvote is a more proper way to say 'thanks'. But anyway you are welcome.

Comment: Hi leeduhem,
Sorry. But i do not have enough reputation to upvote. Hence i couldnt upvote. I am a new user to the website.

Comment: @ShankarNarayanan Hey, do not worry. Upvote is the prefered way, but if you cannot do that, a simple 'thanks' also works.