# Arithmetic pointer with void*

Tags: c, pointers

So I need to create a call to strange_step that results in it printing out the if statement:

```
void strange_step(void* value)
{
    if(*(int*)(value+5) == 15)
    printf("4: Illinois\n");
else
    printf("4: ERROR\n");
}
```

I've tried the following (since to my knowledge, with gcc, it treats void* like a char* so increments 1 byte):

```
int arr[10];
arr[4] = 15;
arr[5] = 15;
arr[3] = 15;
arr[2] = 15;
arr[6] = 15;
arr[7] = 15;
arr[8] = 15;
arr[9] = 15;
//arr[10] = 15;
strange_step(arr);
```

But that just seems to print out random numbers. What am I missing?

Comment: size of `int` is normally 4

Comment: I think you want `if(*((int*)value + 5) == 15)`

Comment: I smell an XY problem. I *seriously* doubt you need (or really even want) a `strange_step` anything like you've shown. What are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: I still get an error when I set arr[1], arr[2] and arr[3] to 15. I guess I'm just having trouble visualizing what happens when value + 5 is called on the void* in the method... Shouldn't it just be going to either arr[5] or arr[1]?

Comment: Note: when you have a problem, better to post output itself rather than just say "random numbers".  It would be _very unusual for `strange_step()` to print any _numbers_.

Comment: I can't modify the method Chux, and yeah I'm not sure it has any application... It is just an exercise to acclimate us to working with C

Comment: `if(*(int*)(value+5) == 15)` is undefined behavior -  it accesses a non-aligned memory address for `int`.  @ldgabbay does present a possible UB result.

Comment: @user3424684 the method is wrong, and participates in non-standard pointer math. `void*` is not required to be treated synonymously as `char*` when it comes to pointer arithmetic. It isn't required to even *work* with pointer arithmetic. For pointer math to work, the pointed-to must have a complete type with a definable stride, and `void` has *none*. [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523145/pointer-arithmetic-for-void-pointer-in-c).

Answer (score 4):

You've got two issues there:

- Doing pointer arithmetics with `void*` is not allowed
- Reading an `int` from a non-aligned pointer may result in an error

However, if you would like to shoehorn 15 into the proper offset, you could do this:

```
char data[32];
*((int*)&data[5]) = 15;
strange_step(data);
```

This prints what you expect ([demo](http://ideone.com/vkkbl3)). However, unless you modify `strange_step` to stop reading unaligned data, your program would rely on undefined behavior.

Comment: That makes sense. Why is the & required before data though? I would think you could just say data[5], but that results in a seg fault.

Comment: @user3424684 it isn't required. You could use `*((int*)(data+5)) = 15;` instead if you wished. It may look the same as in your function but it isn't. Note in your function `value` is a `void*`, (no complete type). Here `data` has complete type (a `char` array).

Comment: @user3424684 An ampersand `&` is required before `data[5]` to take the address of the fifth byte. You could replace `&data[5]` with `(data+5)`.

Answer (score 2):

When you type `value+5`, it's moving the pointer 5 bytes before casting it as an `int*`. Depending on your platform, an `int` is 4 or 8 bytes. On a little-endian machine

```
0F0000000F0000000F0000000F0000000F0000000F0000000F0000000F000000
^         ^
value     value+5
```

You're moving off the `int` boundary, so you're probably finding values that are off by some multiple of 256. I'm guessing you're seeing 251658240 a lot? That's why.

Comment: Yes, the printf statement I placed in the strange_step method was giving 2516582404 repeatedly. So this means that I need the first byte of arr[1] to equal 15? Sorry for the confusion, this is my first time dealing with pointers

Comment: Or actually, could I just use a char array and set the value at array[4] to be the ascii value of 15?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do. What is `strange_step` supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the function to:

```
void strange_step(void* value)
{
  // Treat the input pointer as an `int*`.
  int* ip = (int*)value

  // Use the 6-the value of the array.
  // You could also use if ( ip[5] == 15 )
  if(*(ip+5) == 15)
    printf("4: Illinois\n");
  else
    printf("4: ERROR\n");
}
```