# Difference between void * and void **

Tags: c, void-pointers, pointer-arithmetic

Other than being able to dereference a `void**`, I don't understand the following:

```
void * foo, **bar;
foo++;//error
bar++;//no error
```

Why doesn't the first work but the second does? What's the difference?

Comment: @juanchopanza Strictly speaking both of these post increments are UB.

Comment: @juanchopanza `sizeof(void)` is undefined, so arithmetic on `void` pointers is prohibited.

Comment: @juanchopanza http://i.imgur.com/nnv2UGg.png

Comment: Actually not both. Only the second one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pointer arithmetic for void pointer in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523145/pointer-arithmetic-for-void-pointer-in-c)

Comment: @Quentin: That is a gcc extension (behaves like `char *`) - the most useless imho.

Comment: @Quentin Yes, good point. I got fooled by gcc accepting this.

Comment: Nothing to really pick here, clang accepts it, too. However: `arithmetic on a pointer to void is a GNU extension [-Wpointer-arith]` if `-pendantic`

Comment: Can you post a fully code example that we can actually compile and run?  Your foo/bar statement doesn't make sense without context.

Comment: @QuestionC I ask specifically about allocated space and pointer arithmetic, this is a bit more specific: http://i.imgur.com/CfqG09s.png

Comment: NOTE: `void *` is a generic pointer while `void **` is not.

Comment: @haccks really? so why I can return a `void**` from a function that suppose to return `void*`?

Comment: One is a pointer to the other.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First snippet

```
 foo++;//error
```

because, `foo` is pointer to `void` and you cannot have pointer arithmetic on `void *`, size of the `void` type is not defined.

Second snippet,

```
 bar++;//no error
```

because, `bar` is a pointer to **a pointer to `void`**. So, arithmetic operation is permitted, as the size of a pointer to pointer type is well defined.

*FWIW, don't get surprised if sometimes, [void pointer arithmetic "works" without any error](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.0/gcc/Pointer-Arith.html).*

Comment: It worth mentioning that pointer arithmetic resulting in addresses within an unallocated space is UB. So `bar++` is not safe as well.

Comment: @EugeneSh.Yes my question is specifically for allocated spaces, I tried to make my question as minimal as possible.

Comment: Can you please answer the other part of my question?

Comment: I also added another small question just now.

Comment: @EugeneSh., no arithmetic that goes one item beyond a valid object is allowed, so `bar++` is fine. It is only erroneous when you'd increment further away from a valid object or dereference the pointer.