# Why is void* necessary when char* already exists?

Tags: c

`char *`, as the original generic pointer, does its job well. As I know, a `void *` can do nothing more than a `char *`. What's more, doing arithmetic with `void *` is [not](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3523145/5399734) supported by the standard, which is somewhat error-prone.

So why do we need a `void *` type in C? And when should we use it, rather than `char *`?

Comment: for implicit converversions, and generic object types? ie psuedo object oriented C stuff

Comment: You can't dereference a `void*`, so it prevents you from doing some stupid things.

Comment: What makes you say `char*` is the "original" pointer?

Comment: `char *` makes a lot of assumptions about what is being pointed to. Those assumptions tend to match the view that most people have of memory today, but that doesn't make those views universal. `void *` makes no such assumptions.

Comment: `doing arithmetic with void * is not supported by the standard, which is somewhat error-prone` On the contrary, it catches at compile time potentially bogus arithmetic that would otherwise bomb at runtime.

Comment: voting to reopen, I don't think this is an opinion-based question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> a `void *` can do nothing more than a `char *`

I'm not sure about which can do more things than another but I'm sure that `void*` can do his own jobs which `char *` (or any other type of pointer) cannot.

`void*` is known as a *generic pointer*. Generic pointer:

- Can hold any type of object pointers
- Cannot be dereferenced
- Especially useful when you want a pointer to point to data of different types at different times

And if you try hard to make `char*` do something that `void*` can do, it may possible but will lead to assumption.

If even the compiler does not inform an error or at least a warning about *incompatible type*, we still don't want to see this kind of code:

```
//hi guys, the argument is char* type 
//but you still can pass any other pointer types 
//don't worry!
void func(char * p) {
    ...
}
```

We just need this:

```
//this comment is not need, right?
//you know that you can pass any pointer types
void func(void* p) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: "Generic pointer Can hold any type of pointers" : standard C forbids assignment between function pointer and `void *`. So it's more accurate to say that "generic pointer can hold any type of **object** pointers".