# In C: How to point to different members with offset at run time?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, member

I want to use a single pointer `pt` and a offset `size_t offp` to update the value of either `myNFO.valueA` or `myNFO.valueB` depends on run time conditions.

I can set `pt` to `&myNFO`, but I do not know the proper type of `pt` and how should I calculate `offp`.

Edited:

- I forget to mention the structures I used are allocated at runtime.
- I am using [khash](https://github.com/attractivechaos/klib/blob/master/khash.h), which need to distinguish whether a key exists. If I use `pt = &pNFO->valueA;`, I have to write similar codes twice. Thus I want to determine which member first and then turn to the hash.

---

```
typedef struct {
    uint16_t valueA;
    uint16_t valueB;
    const char * fileName;
} __attribute__ ((__packed__)) Info_t;

Info_t myNFO, *pNFO;

pNFO = calloc(1,sizeof(Info_t));

size_t offp = &(myNFO.valueB) - &(myNFO.valueA);

if (ret==1) {
    pt = pNFO;
} else {
    pt = pNFO + offp;
}

*pt = 100;
```

Comment: The compiler does this for you when you write `myNFO.valueB`. If you want to access an element through a pointer, you can use `pNFO->valueB`. The compiler does the same offset calculation.

Comment: Why not just `uint16_t *pt = ret == 1 ? &pNFO->valueA : &pNFO->valueB;`?

Comment: Why aren't you using `offsetof()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `offsetof()`

```
size_t offp;
if (some condition) {
    offp = offsetof(Info_t, valueA);
} else {
    offp = offsetof(Info_t, valueB);
}
*(uint16_t*)((char*)pNFO + offp) = 100;
```

You need to do all the pointer casting because `offsetof()` returns the offset in bytes. So first you have to cast the struct pointer to `char*` to add the bytes to it, then cast that to a pointer to the element type to assign to it.

Comment: I just notice `size_t offsetof(type, member);` is using `type`.

Comment: And, I think `*(uint16_t*)((void*)pNFO + offp) = 100;` should be better as `void` is type free.

Comment: You can't add to a `void*`.

Comment: `-std=gnu11 -Wall` passed with no warnings under gcc-5 and clang-7 for `*(uint16_t*)((void*)pNFO + offp)`.

Comment: It's a GCC and CLANG extension. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523145/pointer-arithmetic-for-void-pointer-in-c

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do:

```
if (ret==1) {
    pt = &pNFO->valueA;
} else {
    pt = &pNFO->valueB;
}
```

If the intention is to have many more members consider doing:

```
typedef struct {
    uint16_t value[MAX_VALUES];
    const char * fileName;
} __attribute__ ((__packed__)) Info_t;


if (ret < MAX_VALUES) {
    pt = &pNFO->values[ret];
}
```

since `pt` is pointing to a `uint16_t`, it should be a `uint16_t` pointer:

```
uint16_t *pt;
```

Comment: I am using `Info_t` as value of a hash table. If I set `pNFO` first, I need to write 2 similar codes for whether its key exists.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to say first that you are probably doing this the wrong way. But to let you shoot yourself in the foot:

```
uint16_t* pt;
if (ret==1) {
    pt = (uint16_t*)pNFO;
} else {
    pt = (uint16_t*)pNFO + offp;
}
*pt = 100;
```

A better way would be:

```
uint16_t* pt;
if (ret==1) {
    pt = &pNFO->valueA;
} else {
    pt = &pNFO->valueB;
}
*pt = 100;
```

Comment: I am using [khash](https://github.com/attractivechaos/klib/blob/master/khash.h) of the struct, thus it is allocated at runtime.

Comment: @Galaxy Why does it matter that it's allocated at runtime?

Comment: structs are a compile time object. Do you mean that the memory for the struct is allocated at runtime? Doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

It works now. But I think setting `offset` this way seems like *Magic Numbers*, and I want to avoid this if there are some better way.

```
typedef struct {
    uint16_t insertSize;
    uint16_t SD;
    const char * fileName;
} __attribute__ ((__packed__)) BamInfo_t;

KHASH_INIT(bamNFO, kh_cstr_t, BamInfo_t, 1, kh_str_hash_func, kh_str_hash_equal)
bamNFOp = kh_init(bamNFO);

BamInfo_t tbam, *pbam;

while(READFILE) {
    ... ...
    char * id = strdup(name);
    uint16_t *pt;
    size_t offset = 0;
    if (strspn(".SD",name)==3) {
        size_t idLen = strlen(name);
        id[idLen-3] = '\0';
        offset = 1;
    }
    ki = kh_put(bamNFO, bamNFOp, id, &absent);
    if (absent) {
        kh_key(bamNFOp, ki) = id;
        pt = (void*) &tbam;
        *(pt+offset) = atol(value);
        kh_value(bamNFOp, ki) = tbam;
    } else {
        free(id);
        pt = (void*) &kh_value(bamNFOp, ki);
        *(pt+offset) = atol(value);
    }
}
```