# Can't find the Symbol Table(Elf format) (C programming)

Tags: c, elf, objdump, nm

I'm actually recoding the *nm* and *objdump* program. I've already finished *objdump* and it works well, so i'm working on *nm* now.
I'm trying to find the **Symbol table**, in order to do that i run through the **Section header table** like this :

```
while (i < elf->e_shnum)
{
    if (shdr[i].sh_type == SHT_SYMTAB)
        printf("Symbol table found\n");
    i++;
}
```

I never run through this condition, already tried in my objdump program and same problem, can't find SHT_SYMTAB.

This is how i'm getting the **Section header table** :

```
Elf64_Shdr    *shdr;
unsigned char *shstrtab;
void          *data;
Elf64_Ehdr    *elf;

//I reduced the code to make it more readable
data = mmap(NULL, filesize(fd), PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
elf = ((Elf64_Ehdr *)data);
shdr = ((Elf64_Shdr *)(data + elf->e_shoff));
shstrtab = ((unsigned char *)(data + shdr[elf->e_shstrndx].sh_offset));
```

I don't know if i'm doing it right (even if my *objdump* is working perfectly), or if i didn't understand how *nm* works

Thanks for help :)

Comment: I actually replace the data pointeur by the Ehdr one casted in void *, still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't know if i'm doing it right

This:

```
shdr = ((Elf64_Shdr *)(data + elf->e_shoff));
```

adds `.e_shoff` to a `void*` pointer, which invokes [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3524270/50617).

However, GCC [treats arithmetic](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.0/gcc/Pointer-Arith.html) on `void*` as if it were a `char*`, so above code should still produce correct result *iff* you compiled it with GCC.

Your first step should be to verify that the file you are trying to run your program on actually *has* `SHT_SYMTAB` section(s) by running `readelf -WS /path/to/file`.

Assuming it does, your second step should be to verify (in a debugger, or by printing `shdr` and `data`) that the `shdr` you computed matches `Start of section headers` printed by `readelf -h /path/to/file`.

P.S. Note that fully-stripped ELF files do not have a `SYMTAB` section at all (it's not required for execution).

Comment: I found the problem, i was exiting my function when my address (gived by data + shdr[i]._sh_offset) was equal to my shstrtab (which isn't the end of the ELF file). But thanks for the tips on void * :)

Comment: @Drumz "i was exiting my function" -- and this is why you should always try to provide a complete minimal example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) -- the problem was not in the code you showed, so nobody could guess where it was.