# C++ invalid use of void, why?

Tags: c++, pointers

```
char mem[8];
uint64_t *memory{(uint64_t*)(void*)&mem[0]};
std::cout << "diff: " << (void*)memory - (void*)(&mem[0]) << std::endl;
```

Trivial example, error message with gcc is:

```
error: invalid use of ‘void’
std::cout << "diff: " << (void*)memory - (void*)(&mem[0]) << std::endl;
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? reinterpret the `char[]` as a single `uint64_t`?

Comment: You can't perform pointer arithmetic on a `void*`

Comment: @CoryKramer Yeah, pretty much, trying to convert a `char[]` to a `uint64_t` array. I thought it would be easy, but this has got me stumped...

Comment: VS2013 shows error - `void*:unknown size`. Expression must be a pointer to complete object type.

Answer (score 1):

> invalid use of void, why?

It's because size of `void*` (item that stored at this pointer) is unknown .

If you want to calculate distance between pointers in bytes, cast them to pointers of something 1-byte-sized (char*, unsigned char*, uint8_t*, etc.):

`std::cout << "diff: " << (uint8_t*)memory - (uint8_t*)(&mem[0]) << std::endl;`

Comment: What happens if I convert them to `(uint64_t*)` by the way? My assumption would be the difference would still be the same, measured in byte?

Comment: @user3728501 it will measure the distance in the `uint64_t` (8bytes) rounded to bottom. For example, distance `2 bytes` will be the `0 uint64_t`

Comment: "distance 2 bytes will be the 0 uint64_t" - this doesn't make any sense?

Comment: @user3728501 well, it's because it's wrong to count in `uint64_t` when you store `uint8_t` at pointer. Use 1-byte pointers to calc the size (distance) in bytes and pointer to the actual stored items (plain types, objects, structures) to calculate items count.

Answer (score 0):

You can't perform pointer arithmetic with void pointers - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523145/pointer-arithmetic-for-void-pointer-in-c). This is due to `void` not having a defined "size", whereas eg. with `int *x`, you know that `x+1` is going to be `sizeof(int)` bytes further along that the address of `x`.

You can also test it [here](https://godbolt.org/g/x6x1Lc) - removing either of the expressions on the sides of the `-` will let it compile.