# Copy a 2D matrix to a 3D matrix using memcpy in C

Tags: c, arrays, matrix, memcpy

I was instructed to copy all elements from my 2d array, `matrix2D`, to my 3d array `matrix3D` using a single `memcpy` command and then print out the 3d array (separating elements with a comma, rows with a semicolon and each 2d matrix with a new line). Before that, the program takes in user input for dimensions of the 3d matrix, and then all the data to go into the matrix (floats). My functions `malloc2d` and `malloc3d` are working correctly and I am getting no segmentation faults, but when I attempt to `memcpy` the data and then print the 3d matrix, nothing is printing. Here is the code:

```
#include "utilities.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
    unsigned int dim1,dim2,dim3;
    printf("Dimensionality of 3-D matrix ===>");
    scanf("%u",&dim1); //takes user input for dimensions
    scanf("%u",&dim2); //takes user input for dimensions
    scanf("%u",&dim3); //takes user input for dimensions

    //allocating memory for 3d, 2d and 1d matrices
    float*** matrix3D = malloc3D((unsigned int)(dim1), (unsigned int)(dim2), (unsigned int)(dim3), sizeof(float));
    float** matrix2D = malloc2D(dim1, dim2*dim3, sizeof(float));
    float* matrix1D = malloc(dim1*dim2*dim3);

    for(int i = 0; i<(dim1*dim2*dim3); i++){ //taking user input floats
        fscanf(stdin, "%f", &matrix1D[i]);
    }//for

    for(int i = 0; i<(dim1*dim2*dim3); i++){//writing contents of 1d matrix to 2d matrix
        matrix2D[i/(dim2*dim3)][i%(dim2*dim3)] = matrix1D[i];
    }//for

    for (int i = 0; i < dim1; i++){//printing out 2d array as asked
        for (int j = 0; j < (dim2*dim3); j++){
            printf("%0.2f", matrix2D[i][j]);
            if(j==((dim2*dim3)-1)){
                printf(";");
            }//if
            else{
                printf(",");
            }//else
        }//for
    }//for

    printf("\n"); //new line for readability 

    memcpy(matrix3D, matrix2D, dim1*dim2*dim3*sizeof(float));    

    for (int i = 0; i < dim1; i++){//printing out 3d array as asked
        for (int j = 0; j < dim2; j++){
            for(int k = 0; k < dim3; k++){
                printf("%0.2f", matrix3D[i][j][k]);
                if(j==((dim2)-1)){
                    printf(";");
                }//if
                else if(k==((dim3)-1)){
                    printf("\n");
                }//else if
                else{
                    printf(",");
                }//else
            }//for
        }//for
    }//for

    free3D(matrix3D);
    free2D(matrix2D);
    free(matrix1D);

} //main
```

The example input and output given is (I have everything printing except the last 2 lines - the 3d matrix):

[image: example input/output]

Here are malloc2D, malloc3D, free2D and free3D. I was under the impression they were right because they were given to us after none of us were able to get it.

```
void** malloc2D(size_t rows, size_t cols, size_t sizeOfType){
    void* block = malloc(sizeOfType * rows * cols);
    void** matrix = malloc(sizeof(void*) * rows);
    for (int row = 0; row < rows; ++row) {
        matrix[row] = block + cols * row * sizeOfType;
    }//for
    return matrix;
}//malloc2D

void free2D(void*** matrix){
    free((*matrix)[0]);
    free((*matrix));
    *matrix = NULL;
}//free2D

void*** malloc3D(size_t depth, size_t rows, size_t cols, size_t sizeOfType){
    void* block = malloc(sizeOfType * rows * cols * depth);
    void** matrix = malloc(sizeof(void*) * rows * depth);
    void*** matrix2 = malloc(sizeof(void**) * depth);
    for (int depth1 = 0; depth1 < depth; ++depth1) {
        matrix2[depth1] = (void**)(matrix + depth * rows * sizeof(void**));
        for(int row = 0; row < rows; ++row){
            matrix[depth1 * rows + row] = block + (depth1 * rows + row) * cols * sizeOfType;
        }//for
    }//for
    return matrix2;
}//malloc3D

void free3D(void**** matrix){
    free((*matrix)[0][0]);
    free((*matrix)[0]);
    free((*matrix));
    *matrix = NULL;
}//free3D
```

Comment: How do `malloc2D` and `malloc3D` work? Can you post them?  The problem I see, is that `memcpy` copies byte by byte the content from the location pointed to by `matrix2D` into the location pointed to by `matrix3D`. If `matrix3D[i]` and `matrix2d[j]` were initialized with a `malloc`, then you are 1. losing the pointer `matrix3D[i]` by overwriting with `matrix2D[j]`, you would end up with double free issues.

Comment: What is `malloc2D` and `malloc3D`? You are probably not allocating the size correctly. Ie: `sizeof(float)` instead of `sizeof(float **)`. Similarly `float* matrix1D = malloc(dim1*dim2*dim3);` is probably wrong. I don't see `sizeof(float)`.

Comment: just in general, keep in mind that runs with "no segmentation faults" doesn't mean all is well.

Comment: I put the malloc functions up. Like I said, I was under the impression that they were right because they were given, but I wouldn't be surprised if they weren't.

Comment: This setup of contiguous allocation plus a pointer block is just a massive waste of memory, it's not any cheaper to follow a bunch of pointers than it is to do arithmetic to find the location

Comment: Related to, but wholly separate from, [Modifying function that mallocs a 2D array to a 3D array in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48856272/modifying-function-that-mallocs-a-2d-array-to-a-3d-array-in-c) — with the same OP.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to use a single `memcpy` to copy a 2d array into a 3d array is if the data for each of the 2d and 3d arrays are flat in memory.

The allocation functions you were provided show that the data for each are contiguous. Therefore, you need to copy the data section of the 2d array into the data section of the 3d array.

Since the data is contiguous, it follows that the data section is located at the address of the first element of the arrays. Hence, the data section for the 2d array begins at `&matrix2D[0][0]`, and the data section for the 3d array begins at `&matrix3D[0][0][0]`. Given the semantics of array syntax, these expressions are the same as `matrix2D[0]` and `matrix3D[0][0]`, respectively.

Assuming that `matrix1D` is initialized properly:

```
memcpy(matrix2D[0], matrix1D, dim1*dim2*dim3*sizeof(float));
memcpy(matrix3D[0][0], matrix2D[0], dim1*dim2*dim3*sizeof(float));
```

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this allocation code a couple of times, and I always point out that
while it's a clever way of allocating space for double/triple pointers, you
might encounter problems when not used carefully.

Let's take a look at `malloc2D`:

```
void** malloc2D(size_t rows, size_t cols, size_t sizeOfType){
    void* block = malloc(sizeOfType * rows * cols);
    void** matrix = malloc(sizeof(void*) * rows);
    for (int row = 0; row < rows; ++row) {
        matrix[row] = block + cols * row * sizeOfType;
    }//for
    return matrix;
}
```

Like I've pointed out before, [`void*` pointer arithmetic is illegal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46238658/1480131) in C,
GNU C has an extension for that. But let's assume this works as intended:

The first `malloc` reserves `rows  * cols` spaces for objects of size
`sizeOfType`. The second `malloc` reserves space for `rows` pointers. The memory
layout of this is (the arrows represent: pointer points to):

[image]

Note that `block` and `matrix` and different memory locations, the `matrix[i]`
(`i`th row)
point to the start of a sequence at `block[j]` (start of a new colum, multiple
of `cols`).

The `malloc3D` is basically doing the same but multiple times (`depth` times).
The basic memory layout is is similar with one more layer of
pointers<sup>1</sup>:

[image]

Note that `block`, `matrix` and `matrix2` are different memory locations, the
`matrix2[i]` point to the start of a sequence at `matrix[j]` and the
`matrix[j]` points to the start of a sequence at `block[k]`.

Now when you do:

```
memcpy(matrix3D, matrix2D, dim1*dim2*dim3*sizeof(float));
```

you are **not** copying the contents pointed to by `matrix2D` into the contents pointed
to by `matrix3D`; the contents of `matrix2D` are not `float`s, they are
pointers! So you are in fact copying the pointers of `matrix2D` in `matrix3D`.
That will cause trouble because the pointers are not of the same type (see the
graphs): `matrix2D` pointers point to `float*` and `matrix3D` pointers point to
`float**`, so when you dereference them, you will get wrong results, because you
are dereferencing from incorrect addresses. As jxh points out in [his/her answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48894370/1480131), this would
only work when the values are flat in memory, but they are not, even though
`block` is flatt, but you are not accessing `block` directly, you are accessing
it through pointers.

That means that

```
free3D(matrix3D);
free2D(matrix2D);
```

will get you into trouble, because the first `free` does not free the memory
reserved by `malloc3D`, as it has been overwritten by the `memcpy`. `free2D`
would attempt to free the same memory which you are not allowed to.

You would have to go down to the `block` level and use `memcpy` there, for
example this is OK:

```
for(int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
    memcpy(matrix3D[0][i], matrix2D[i], cols * sizeof(float));
```

---

**Fotenotes**

<sup>1</sup>Because of the limited space in the graph, I use `depth == 2`, so
that's why `matrix2+1` points to `matrix+2`.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain this extensively. I understand what you mean about the void* pointer arithmetic, however I didn't change it because it was given and we are specifically asked not to mess with the given code.  This explanation helped me to understand allocation and freeing much better.