# Should std::byte pointers be used for pointer arithmetic?

Tags: c++, memory, byte, void, pointer-arithmetic

It seems [`std::byte`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/byte) has become the way (in C++17) to work with buffers holding object representations, but it's unclear whether this intent still allows for performing pointer arithmetic.

The **question** in the title is intentionally phrased as **should** because I'm looking for recommendation. For example, `void*` can be used for pointer arithmetic as gcc extensions but are not standard (at least this is [true for C](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.0/gcc/Pointer-Arith.html)), hence a possibility but [not a recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523145/pointer-arithmetic-for-void-pointer-in-c).

I know the motivation for `std::byte` is to detach the character and the numeric aspects from the concept of *byte*. But at the same time, does pointer arithmetic stay?

EDIT: adjusted to clarify that I'm looking to do "pointer arithmetic" using `std::byte*` not the numerical value of pointers stores in `std::byte`s

Comment: Are you asking if it is okay to iterate over an object using a `std::byte*`?

Comment: Not quite sure I understand what you're asking, to perform pointer arithmetic on a buffer, you should just use a pointer to the same type as the current region of the buffer. Iterating over object members is a big nono altogether.

Comment: What do you call *using `std::byte` for pointer arithmetic*? Could you at least give an example?

Comment: Could you add some code example to clarify what you mean with "using std::byte for pointer arithmetic"?

Comment: @NathanOliver yes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, `std::byte*` can be used for pointer arithmetic.

And you can even do things like

```
struct foo{int x,y};
foo f;
int* ptr_to_y = reinterpret_cast<int*>(reinterpret_cast<std::byte*>(&f)+offsetof(foo,y));
```

You do have to be careful that your locations are reachable through your operations.  Just because pointers-as-integers gets the right result doesn't mean that the C++ code is doing defined behavior.  There are a number of quirks in C++ around permitting the optimizer to "know" that a certain value cannot be modified.

```
struct loc {
  int x,y;
};

void f( int* );

loc work( loc l ) {
  l.x=3;
  f(&l.y);
  return l;
}
```

in the above case, someone who used the `&l.y` pointer to do pointer arithmetic (within `f`) and modify `l.x`, regardless of if they went to `std::byte*` or not, would be doing undefined behavior.  The compiler is allowed to assume the returned `l` will have an `.x` value of `3`.

These are not new pitfalls introduced by `std::byte*`.

Comment: That's got me to thinking - is the cast to/from (and arithmetic using) `byte*` permitted as a special case in the same way that it is with `char*` and `void*`? I guess that's the question after all

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes, `byte*` gets the same special treatement as `char*`, except it doesn't have the double-meaning of "pointer to null terminated string" and the like (so `std::ostream& << std::byte*` doesn't iterate through memory looking for a null byte, as was the fashion at the time).  And you cannot do non-bit math on `byte`s, like `+2`, without first converting it to an integral type.  I agree the question needs work, but I strongly believe this is what they are asking.

Comment: Thanks for answering, yeah that would some of the things I'd be doing (except in your example I'd use `memcpy` to keep with strict aliasing).

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I made a very brief attempt to find the relevant wording but don't remember where it is

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit it's at [reinterpret_cast > Type Aliasing](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast#Type_aliasing).

Comment: @haelix I'm talking about the standard - but tbh its inclusion on that page is enough satisfaction for me!

Comment: I'm not buying the final passage though. If aliasing worked that way we'd never be able to use pointers to _anything_ with any certainty. However, if `f()` were to take something other than a `int*`, `char*`, `unsigned char*` or (it turns out) `std::byte*`, then that would indeed be a problem. And I believe that's the point in this question.

Comment: But compilers use a weaker aliasing rule -> they assume the callee may access any part of the complete object.