# What does assigning a value to a function that returns a pointer do in C? *function=value

Tags: c, function, pointers

So I am looking at [this](https://cstack.github.io/db_tutorial/) and the guy is continuously using

```
uint32_t *internalNodeNumKeys(void *node)
{
    return (uint32_t *)(node + INTERNAL_NODE_NUM_KEYS_OFFSET);
}

*internalNodeNumKeys(root) = 1;
```

What does this do? Somewhere I remember him saying that because these functions return pointers they can be used as setters but what do they set?

Comment: That's not a function pointer; that's a function that returns a pointer.

Comment: `node + INTERNAL_NODE_NUM_KEYS_OFFSET` is [not legal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523145/pointer-arithmetic-for-void-pointer-in-c).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function returns a pointer to `int`, the expression `*internalNodeNumKeys(root) = 1;` is parsed as:

```
*(internalNodeNumKeys(root)) = 1;
```

Postfix operators such as `()` for function call bind more tightly than prefix operators such as `*` for dereferencing.

Note also that `internalNodeNumKeys` is highly non portable:

- Performing pointer arithmetics on `void` pointers is non portable, `node` should be cast as `(unsigned char *)` before the addition.
- Casting an arbitrary offset into the object pointed to by `node` as a pointer to `int` may have undefined behavior, the programmer is playing with fire at this point.

Comment: Yes, but as it has been addressed in one of the comments to the question by Jamesdlin, `node + INTERNAL_NODE_NUM_KEYS_OFFSET` is illegal, as it is doing pointer arithmetic with a `void *`.  It should be better to have declared the parameter as `char *` instead.