# Preventing compilation of void** pointer arithmetic in C

Tags: c, pointers, void-pointers

This is the same concept as [Pointer arithmetic for void pointer in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523145/pointer-arithmetic-for-void-pointer-in-c) except my data type is a `void**` instead of a `void*`

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int foo [] = {1, 2};
    void* bar = &foo;
    void** baz = &bar;
    void** bazplusone = baz + 1;

    // cast to void* to make printf happy
    printf("foo points to %p\n", (void*)foo);
    printf("baz points to the address of bar and is %p\n", (void*)baz);
    printf("bazplusone is an increment of a void** and points to %p\n",(void*)bazplusone);
    return 0;
}
```

which results in the following output for my version of gcc:

```
foo points to 0x7ffeee54e770
bar is a void* cast of foo and points to 0x7ffeee54e770
baz points to the address of bar and is 0x7ffeee54e760
bazplusone is an increment of a void** and points to 0x7ffeee54e768
```

I have two questions:

1. Is this legal according to the C standard?
2. Assuming #1 is
   false, is there a way to generate a compiler error? Neither
   `-pendandic-errors` nor `-Wpointer-arith` complains about this small
   program

Comment: It is a GCC extension. I haven't tried it, but did you try `-std=c11 -pedantic` ?

Comment: `-std=c11 -pedantic` doesn't result in any errors

Comment: With the little test I just wrote I get a warning: `void-math.c:7:16: warning: pointer of type ‘void *’ used in arithmetic [-Wpointer-arith]` from GCC

Comment: Oh, by the way, math on a `void**` is completely legal. It increments the pointer to void* by the size of void*.

Comment: Like, you can't have an array of `void` but you can have an array of `void*`.

Comment: As long as `sizeof(t)` is defined for type `t`, then arithmetic on a `t *` is well-defined.  In this case, `t` is `void *`.  Since its size is defined, then arithmetic on a `void **` is also well-defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I misunderstood what you were doing at first. I thought you were doing math on a `void*`. That is not allowed by the C Standard, but is allowed by a GCC (and clang) extension that treats it as math on a `char*`.

However, you are doing math on a `void**` which is perfectly OK. A `void*` is the size of a pointer and is not an undefined value. You can make arrays of `void*`s and you can do pointer math on a `void**` because it has a defined size.

So you will never get a warning for `void**` math because it is not a problem.

Comment: “Allowed” should be changed to “defined.” The C standard does not prohibit programmers or programs from doing things it does not define; they are generally allowed. And, if a C implementation that accepts strictly conforming programs accepts a program that does this (say because because it defines an extension), then the program is conforming as defined by the C standard.

Comment: “A `void*` is the size of a pointer” should say “A `void *` has a known size.” “The size of a pointer” is not a fixed quantity; different types of pointers may have different sizes within a C implementation.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Arithmetic on `void*` values is a constraint violation, not merely undefined behavior. A conforming implementation must diagnose it, and may either reject it or accept it.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Yes, it is a constraint violation. Nonetheless, the sentences I wrote above are true.