# Use of char* over void* in pointer arithmetic

Tags: c, casting, pointer-arithmetic

I am going through this [code](https://github.com/jtsiomb/dynarr) for learning purposes and have a question about [this line](https://github.com/jtsiomb/dynarr/blob/master/dynarr.c#L31):

```
return (char*)desc + sizeof *desc;
```

Why is `desc` cast to `char*`?
I tried to mimic it with my own code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Test {
    int value;
};

int main() {

    struct Test* test = malloc(sizeof test);

    struct Test* test1 = (void*)test + sizeof *test;
    test1->value = 1;
    printf("%d\n", test1->value);

    struct Test* test2 = (void*)test1 + sizeof *test;
    test2->value = 10;
    printf("%d\n", test2->value);

}
```

This also works. But, what is the difference? Why is `char*` used?

Note: I used `void*` just to see if that works. As `char*` has nothing to do with the `struct` in question, I simply thought, "What if I use `void*` over there?". A more specific question could be, why not `int*` or `float*` & why `char*` is used?

Comment: Standard C doesn't allow arithmetic on `void` pointers.  You're probably using a nonstandard extension, e.g. gcc supports this.

Comment: Contrary to your beliefs, your code doesn't actually work. Remember that for any pointer or array `p` and index `i`, the expression `*(p + i)` is exactly equal to `p[i]`. That means you make `test1` point to `test[1]` and `test2` point to `test[2]`.

Comment: Also note that `sizeof test` might be different from `sizeof *test`.

Comment: Indeed, you probably wanted that first line to have `malloc(3 * sizeof *test)`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, by saying "it works", I meant, the code got complied & I am able to see the logs printed with expected value, when I ran the executable. As NateEldredge mentioned, I am using gcc.

Comment: @NateEldredge, `3` because, `Test` initialized 3 times? If yes, I got that. 
I was exploring that code to understand how the array is dynamically resized.

Comment: @NateEldredge, `Standard C doesn't allow arithmetic on void pointers`, okay! But, could you explain why `char*` is used? Why not `int*` or any other pointer?

Comment: Pointer arithmetic is done in the size of the base-type. So for `(char*)desc + sizeof *desc;` the base-type is `char` so it add `sizeof *desc * sizeof(char)` *bytes* to the pointer. If using `int` (as in `(int*)desc + sizeof *desc;`) then the base type is `int` so it adds `sizeof *desc + sizeof(int)` *bytes*, and with the common size of `int` being four bytes, it add four times as many bytes compared to the `char*` version.

Comment: @NateEldredge: The C standard does not **define** arithmetic on `void` pointers. It does **allow** arithmetic on `void` pointers. The C standard allows and invites extensions to the language, and GCC and Clang implementation such an extension.

Comment: The code will also compile if you replace all numbers with twice the value. That does not tell anything whether it is correct or "works".

Comment: @explorer, because you end up writing to three different `struct Test` objects, located one after the other.  So if the buffer is smaller than `3 * sizeof(struct Test)`, you are writing off the end of it.  The other point that Some programmer dude was making is that `sizeof test` is the size of a *pointer* to `struct Test`, because that's the type of `test`; it is not the size of a `struct Test` object.  So that's why it should be `3 * sizeof *test`, or maybe `3 * sizeof(struct Test)`, but not `3 * sizeof test`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pointer arithmetic for void pointer in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523145/pointer-arithmetic-for-void-pointer-in-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Why Pointers to Characters Are Used

> Why is desc cast to char*? … As `char*` has nothing to do with the `struct` in question…

In C, every object except a bit-field is composed of a sequence of bytes.<sup>1</sup> Converting the address of an object to `char *` yields a pointer to the first byte of the object, and you can access the individual bytes of the object using that pointer.

In standard C, pointer arithmetic uses units of the pointed-to type. For a pointer `p` of type `struct Test`, `p+1` points to the next structure after `p`, `p+2` points to the structure after that, and so on. For a pointer `q` of type `char *`, `q+1` points to the next `char` after q, `q+2` points to `char` after that, and so on.

Thus, to access the individual bytes of an object, you can convert its address to a `char *` and use that.

### Why Other Kinds of Pointers Are Not Used

> A more specific question could be, why not `int*` or `float*` & why `char*` is used?

`char *` is used because all objects in C, except bit-fields, are defined to be represented as sequences of bytes. They are not necessarily sequences of `int` or `float`. `unsigned char *` and `signed char *` may also be used, and `unsigned char *` may be preferable due to complications from sign issues.

The C standard has special rules about accessing objects using character pointers, so it guarantees that accessing the bytes of an object this way will work. In contrast, accessing objects using `int *` or `float *` may not work. The compiler is allowed to expect that a pointer to an `int` will not be used to access a `float` object, and, when it is generating machine instructions for a program, it may write those instructions based on that expectation. Using a character pointer prevents the compiler from assuming that a `char *` does not point to the same place as another kind of pointer.

### Why Pointers to Void Work

> Note: I used `void*` just to see if that works.

For pointer arithmetic to work, the compiler needs to know the size of the pointed-to object. When 1 is added to a pointer to a `struct Test`, the compiler needs to know how many bytes to adjust the internal address by.

`void` is an incomplete type. There are no `void` objects, and `void` has no size. (The size is not zero. There is no size.) Because of this, the C standard does not define any meaning for `p+1` when `p` is a `void *`.

However, [GCC defines arithmetic on `void *` as an extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-10.1.0/gcc/Pointer-Arith.html#Pointer-Arith). It works as if `void` had a size of 1 byte. Clang supports this too.

Because of this extension, doing arithmetic with `void *` pointers is essentially the same as doing arithmetic with `char *` pointers.

This extension is unnecessary; any code doing arithmetic on `void *` could be rewritten to use `char *` instead. Sometimes this requires extra casts to convert pointer types, and that could be the reason the extension was added to GCC (to reduce the amount of code required and make it look better).

You can disable this extension with the switches `-Werror -Wpointer-arith`, or you can generally request closer conformance to standard C with `-Werror -std=c18 -pedantic`. I used `-Werror -std=c18 -pedantic` whenever possible, and I recommend it.

### Footnote

<sup>1</sup> Bit-fields are sequences of bits that are held in some larger container of bytes and may happen to coincide with bytes.