# In this below C code related to pointers and its output, then why doesn't the value a[1] i.e 20 get stored at consecutive address de9?

Tags: c, pointers, memory, garbage

In the Below code , each location can hold 32 bit signed data. So, why doesn't the value a[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ay49.png) i.e 20 get stored at consecutive address de9? Array should store the data at consecutive memory location right?  I know that the sizeof(int) in this online gdb compiler is 4 bytes but how can it be related to the storing of 20 at 4 locations away? Am I missing some basic concepts?

```
  int main()
    {
     int a[2]= {214748368,20};
       
       void *ptr1 = &a;
       void *ptr2= &a;
       
       ptr1++;
       ptr2 = ptr2;
       
       printf("%d \n", *(int*)ptr2);
       printf("\n Pointer table");
       printf("\n Data : %d at address : %p", *(int*)ptr2, ptr2);
       ptr2=ptr2+1;
       printf("\n Data : %d at address : %p", *(int*)ptr2, ptr2);
       ptr2=ptr2+1;
       printf("\n Data : %d at address : %p", *(int*)ptr2, ptr2);
       ptr2=ptr2+1;
       printf("\n Data : %d at address : %p", *(int*)ptr2, ptr2);
       ptr2=ptr2+1;
       printf("\n Data : %d at address : %p", *(int*)ptr2, ptr2);
       return 0;
    }
```

[Code Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ay49.png)

Comment: `ptr1++;` advances 1-past the end of `a`, `ptr2 = ptr2;` makes no sense. `void *ptr1 = a;` would allow `ptr1++;` to point to the 2nd element of `a`.

Comment: That is because `int` have `4`(here) bytes width so, it is going to be stored after `4` bytes i.e. `a[0]` at `0x7fff97fb9de9` and `a[1]` at `0x7fff97fb9dec`

Comment: The problem with `ptr1` is when you use the `&` (address of) operator on `a`, e.g. `&a`, the resulting pointer is a *pointer-to-array* `int[2]` instead of allowing normal array/pointer conversion to take place via [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1 Other Operands - Lvalues, arrays, and function designators(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3)

Comment: Constraint violation for trying to do arithmetic on `void*`. Your compiler was obligated to issue a diagnostic message about this, but many c compilers are non-conforming in this way. You may be able to un-break the compiler by giving it the right command line argument to actually do its job correctly.

Comment: By using untyped pointer (void *), arithmetic on pointer is done assuming single byte data. Declaring `ptr1` and `ptr2` as `int *` would correctly advance one slot by adding 1 (and as a bonus, would remove the need of casting).

Comment: This program is broken. Pointer arithmetic on `void` pointers is a non-standard gcc extension. Accessing bytes in the middle of an `int` object via an `int` pointer is undefined behaviour. You can examine individual bytes but you need to do so via a `char` pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you increase a pointer in C pointer arithmetic is used. So if your pointer `a` is of type `int *` it will be increased by `sizeof(int)`. However your pointer is of type `void *`. This is not intended, apparently it is increased by one byte (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523145/pointer-arithmetic-for-void-pointer-in-c)).

As the size of an `int` on your system is 32 bits or 4 bytes you have to increase the pointer four times by one byte to reach the next element in your array.

You can avoid this issue by defining your pointers as `int *`:

```
int *ptr1 = &a;
int *ptr2 = &a;
```

In this case incrementing the pointer once (`ptr2++`) will give you the next element.