# Is the iov_len field of an iovec well-defined?

Tags: c, posix, standards

According to [Pointer arithmetic for void pointer in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523145/pointer-arithmetic-for-void-pointer-in-c), arithmetic with void pointers is not allowed. Yet, the `iovec` structure looks like so:

```
struct iovec {
    void *iov_base;
    size_t iov_len;
};
```

This is defined in the [POSIX standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_uio.h.html), and the `iov_len` field is described as the somewhat vague "The size of the memory pointed to by *iov_base*". Since `iovec` is just a data structure, I wondered if the functions that accept it as input parameters define how they use the `iov_len` field, but both [`readv`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/readv.html) and [`writev`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/writev.html) desribe it, again vaguely, as "the length of an area of memory."

For some functions, the meaning of the `iov_len` field does seem to be explicitly defined. For example, the [`recvmsg`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sendmsg.html) specification says the "*iov_len* field gives [the storage area's] size in bytes".  Additionally, [`recv`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/recv.html), which accepts a void pointer and length, properly defines the length parameter as the length of the buffer in bytes.

My question: Is the meaning of the `iov_len` field well-defined in these cases where it's defined as the length of a buffer?

Comment: Is your beef with `iov_len` that it is a bit under-specified and doesn't tell you that the size is supposed to be in bytes, or is there something else? Also, the fact that pointer arithmetics is not allowed for `void*` seems to be irrelevant to the overall question.

Comment: I guess I'm being pedantic, but I would have thought pedantry is important when writing a standard... Also, if `void*` arithmetic was allowed (i.e. if `void` was a complete type), then the length could be naturally assumed to be the number of `void` elements in the buffer. As it stands, because `void` is an incomplete type, `iov_len` has no units, so to refer to it as a length is technically meaningless.

Comment: But I'm also wondering if I'm missing a subtlety. For instance the term 'size' or 'length' may be defined elsewhere in the standard to mean size in bytes.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're just overthinking here.  "Size" here definitely means "size in bytes", and in the cases you mention I don't think there's any meaningful difference between the words "size" and "length".  There's no subtlety that you're missing.

It might be a tiny bit sloppy that they didn't say "in bytes" as they do in many other places, and you could file a defect report if you really want, but I don't see much room for confusion as there's really no other sensible interpretation.

Nobody is claiming that `void` has a size, but it's very common to use `void *` as a pointer to a generic buffer whose size is denominated in bytes; using `void *` instead of `unsigned char *` makes it convenient for you to pass a pointer to some other type without casting.

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty common to deal with `void *` along with explicit size. It allows you to forget the type of object you are referencing and thus reuse same the same `void *` field to store different types of data without `union`s at all.

The reason why you need size is typically for `memcpy`, which copies continuous memory. That way you are able not to only keep your data in a `void *` (you know desired size, so you can `malloc` it safely), but also pass it over.

Of course, you can always get back to typed world by casting your `void *` to some other type, for example `size_t *`.

---

`void *` are often used to implement "generic" data structures in C or for higher order functions. For example here is `qsort` definition:

```
void qsort(
   void *base,
   size_t number,
   size_t width,
   int (__cdecl *compare )(const void *, const void *)
);
```