# arithmetic on Void Pointers in C

Tags: c

I have a problem with understanding arithmetic on void pointers,suppose we have this pointer:

```
int x = 10;
int* p = &x;
```

so if we want get the address of x we printf p and if we wanna get the value of that address we just printf *p so everything is okay till now, but when i saw this example:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a[2] = {1, 2};
    void *ptr = &a;
    ptr = ptr + sizeof(int);
    printf("%d", *(int *)ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

the result of the program is 2 and i dont know why ?

why not the program prints zero as a  result , because this line means:

```
ptr = ptr + sizeof(int);
```

**new address of(ptr) = the current address of(ptr) + 4(size of int)**

and the value of void pointer is 1 so the shift will be x[5] and its not exist and it must print 0 as a result, why it prints 2 ?

this is the page that i get the example from :

> https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/void-pointer-c-cpp/

Comment: void pointer arithmetic doesn't really make sense. GeeksForGeeks is not a good reference for C or C++, don't trust what you see there.

Comment: @Mat , could you give me a good reference for C ? site or book ?

Comment: Allowing arithmetic on void pointers is a controversial, nonstandard extension.  If you 're thinking in assembly language, where pointers are just addresses, arithmetic on void pointers makes sense, and adding 1 just adds 1.  But if you're thinking in C terms, using C's model of pointer arithmetic, adding 1 to any pointer `p` actually adds `sizeof(*p)` to the address, and this is what you want pointer arithmetic to do, but since `sizeof(void)` is 0, it breaks down.  If you're thinking in C terms you don't mind, but if you're thinking in assembler you want it to work, thus the extension.