# Clearing memory buffers securely to prevent data leaks in C

Tags: c, design-patterns, secure-coding

So I'm asking about this here purely because I can't find any guidelines/explanation for how this works anywhere else.

I am trying to clear a memory buffer after use to prevent a leak of highly sensitive data when the memory goes out of scope but don't really understand how this is implemented. The Windows API for C does provide a function to securely fill a memory block with zeros, but the few practical implementations I've come across all use some kind of conditional syntax depending on the architecture of the machine.

For example this is how DiskCryptor implemented it:

```
/* zero memory secure (prevent compiler optimization) */
#if defined(BOOT_LDR)
#define burn(_ptr, _len) { volatile char *_p = (volatile char*)(_ptr); size_t _s = (_len); while (_s--) *_p++ = 0; }
#else
#define burn(_ptr, _len) { RtlSecureZeroMemory(_ptr, _len); }
#endif
```

Here's another example; VeraCrypt's "burn" macro:

```
#if defined(_WIN32) && !defined(_UEFI)
#define burn(mem,size) do { volatile char *burnm = (volatile char *)(mem); size_t burnc = size; RtlSecureZeroMemory (mem, size); while (burnc--) *burnm++ = 0; } while (0)
#else
#define burn(mem,size) do { volatile char *burnm = (volatile char *)(mem); int burnc = size; while (burnc--) *burnm++ = 0; } while (0)
#endif
```

Can anyone guide me on how this works and how I can do it right without making any security loopholes in the process?

Comment: FYI: C23 has (*will have*) `memset_explicit()` just for that very reason. See 7.26.6.2 in https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n3096.pdf

Comment: If you link your binary against the glibc-2.25+ you can use  the function `void explicit_bzero(void s[.n], size_t n)`. It guarantees that compiler optimizations will not remove the erase  operation if the compiler deduces that the operation is "unnecessary". [bezero(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/bzero.3.html).

Comment: @cforler `void explicit_bzero(void s[.n], size_t n)`?!?! Ooof. An array of `void`?!?! That breaks any compiler that doesn't support the "void is a type" GNU abomination, err, extension.  FWIW, the actual prototype in `strings.h` on my Ubuntu 20.04 install is `extern void explicit_bzero (void *__s, size_t __n) __THROW __nonnull ((1));`

Comment: @Andrew Henle  I did not understand your point because `void s[.n]` is simply a more  precise notation for `void *__s` since it includes the length of the
memory block to which `s` is pointing.

By the way, my `/usr/include/string.h` contains the following prototype:

`extern void explicit_bzero(void *__s, size_t __n) __THROW __nonnull((1)) __fortified_attr_access(__write_only__, 1, 2);`

Both of our variants are consistent with the GNU manpage notation:
`void explicit_bzero(void s[.n], size_t n).`

Comment: You could also use a memory allocator that zeros out data before either reusing the same memory or returning it to the system. This would provide a good layer of security from junk memory scraping... but it won't provide safety if some other program can access your "live" (allocated) memory.

Comment: @cforler You can't have an array of any type unless the size of the element is known.  [As `void` doesn't have a size per the C standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.5p19) it can not be part of an array.  *since it includes the length of the memory block to which s is pointing*  Which means `void` has a size despite the standard's "The void type comprises an empty set of values; it is an incomplete object type that cannot be completed."  `void s[.n]` is in no way consistent with `void *s` as `void s[.n]` is non-portable and not strictly-compliant C.

Comment: @cforler I'd be surprised if any actual prototype exposed in any version of `strings.h` is actually `void explicit_bzero(void s[.n], size_t n);`  The prototype in both https://codebrowser.dev/gtk/include/string.h.html#explicit_bzero and https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/string/string.h#L435 is `extern void explicit_bzero (void *__s, size_t __n) __THROW __nonnull ((1));` despite what the GNU man page might state.

Comment: @cforler See also [Pointer arithmetic for void pointer in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523145/pointer-arithmetic-for-void-pointer-in-c).  Note that array dereferences for `a[n]` are [literally defined in pointer arithmetic as `*(a + n)`](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.1p2) and that rules out any array of `void` "vaules".

Comment: @AndrewHenle First of all, I am familiar with the types `void`, `void` pointers, and arrays in C. The official glibc/Linux man page [bzero(3)](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/docs/man-pages/man-pages.git/tree/man3/bzero.3) switched in 2022 from C prototypes to Variable Length Array (VLA) syntax for declaring function parameters.

Here is the related git commit message:
"Various pages: SYNOPSIS: Use VLA syntax in 'void *' function parameters
Use VLA syntax also for 'void *', even if it's a bit more unusual." -- Alex Colomar

Comment: @cforler So you cite another glibc/Linux man page that [doesn't match the actual implementation](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/string/bzero.c)? So GNU man pages are sloppy. If you were familiar with the definition of `void` as a type that "**cannot** be completed", you'd know that arrays of `void` are not strictly compliant C and are non-portable.  And yep, the GNU man page for `memset()` also fails to match [the C standard itself](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.24.6.1). Man pages that don't match the C standard or even their own implementation are bad sources.

Comment: @AndrewHenle 
1. The VLA syntax `void *memset(void s[.n], int c, size_t n);` and the C prototype `void *memset(void *s, int c, size_t n);` are equivalent. You're telling me that I don't know numbers because I write 020 instead of 16. :-)

Comment: 2. A five-year-old fork from the glibc is not the actual glibc. You will find the actual glibc [here](https://sourceware.org/git/glibc.git), where the last commit was about 90 minutes ago.

The official [glibc homepage](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/documentation.html) refers to the [Linux man-pages project](https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/) that has started using the VLA syntax instead of C prototypes.

3. Note that C11 was replaced by C17 in 2018. 

BTW, I personally prefer C prototypes over the VLA syntax,too.

Comment: @cforler You mean [like this `extern void *memcpy (void *__restrict __dest, const void *__restrict __src, size_t __n) __THROW __nonnull ((1, 2));`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=string/string.h;h=c0773d11d85b90679d759b5b4a6335577445f3da;hb=HEAD#l43) or [this `extern void explicit_bzero (void *__s, size_t __n) __THROW __nonnull ((1)) __fortified_attr_access (__write_only__, 1, 2);`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=string/string.h;h=c0773d11d85b90679d759b5b4a6335577445f3da;hb=HEAD#l466).  NB neither of those use VLA syntax with arrays of `void`.

Comment: @cforler And **neither** match the man pages that use the VLA format.

Comment: @cforler Note also [the actual implementation of `explicit_bzero()`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=string/explicit_bzero.c;h=1233246e951b21f058d6598b01d44bdefe595117;hb=HEAD) is `void explicit_bzero (void *s, size_t len)`, which also fails to match the man page.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I think I understand why we're talking past each other. :-)

You think that `void s[.n]` translates to `void s[n]` instead of `void *s`. Note that `void s[.n]` is not valid in `C`, and it should translate as follows: The variable `s` points to a block of memory of (at least) n bytes.