# error C2036: 'void *' : unknown size

Tags: c, visual-studio, void, void-pointers

I am working with a C project using visual studio. I tried to compile the following code:

```
void shuffle(void *arr, size_t n, size_t size)
{
        ....
        memcpy(arr+(i*size), swp,  size);
        ....  
}
```

I get the following error with Visual studio Compiler:

```
error C2036: 'void *' : unknown size
```

The code compile well with GCC. How to solve this error?

Comment: But you are sure that you are compiling with a C compiler?

Comment: Yes, It is removed.

Comment: However you cannot index pointer of type void. You can try to cast it to char so that each increment is of one byte

Comment: Because the compiler does not know what size a `void*` pointer is, although there could be GCC extension that permits it. To do pointer arithmetic, you have to know the size of the data it points to. Note that adding `1` to a pointer to a 32-bit `int` will add `4` to the pointer itself. Just like with array indexing, where you access the second element with `arr[1]` not with `arr[4]`.

Comment: Thanks all for your interesting remarks.

Comment: @layzak: Yes, you are right. I fix it. :))

Comment: Just to note that, void pointer arithmetic is a [GCC extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Pointer-Arith.html).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can't perform pointer arithmetic on a `void *` because `void` doesn't have a defined size.

Cast the pointer to `char *` and it will work as expected.

```
memcpy((char *)arr+(i*size), swp,  size);
```

Comment: BTW: More information can be found in the answers of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3498850).